# Cannot validate certificate with crypto/x509 and RSA SSA PSS

Tags: go, ssl, rsa, pki

I'm trying to validate a certificate against a list of roots injected by hand into the chain (or "pool" as it is called in `crypto/x509`). No errors or anything here.

When I try to validate the certificate itself, I get the following error:

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: cannot verify signature: algorithm unimplemented" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "Root CA 06/22/RSA")
```

So far, this validation isn't failing due to "trust" issues, it's failing because the signature algorithm of the certificate isn't implemented and therefore cannot be validated. When I pop the certificate open in OpenSSL, I see the following details:

```
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
         Hash Algorithm: sha512
         Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha512
          Salt Length: 0x01BE
```

It seems that for some reason, RSA SSA PSS isn't implemented or -if it is- the certificate is having some sort of issue.

```golang
        payload, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(validationRequest.Certificate)
        if err != nil {
            log.WithFields(log.Fields{"route": req.RequestURI, "method": req.Method}).Warnf("could not decode base64: %s", validationRequest.Certificate)
            err := rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]string{"error": "payload is not valid base64"})
            if err != nil {
                log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
            }
        } else {
            block, _ := pem.Decode(payload)
            if block == nil {
                err := rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]string{"error": "certificate is not a valid PEM"})
                if err != nil {
                    log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
                }
            } else {
                certificate, err := cryptoX509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
                if err != nil {
                    log.Errorf("failed to parse certificate: %v", err.Error())

                    err = rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]string{"error": fmt.Sprintf("certificate could not be parsed from bytes: %v", err.Error())})
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
                    }
                } else {

                    _, ok := certificate.PublicKey.(*rsa.PublicKey)

                    // If weird or non-existing key
                    if !ok {
                        err = rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusNotAcceptable, map[string]string{"error": "certificate does not contain a valid key, or the key is missing"})
                        if err != nil {
                            log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
                        }
                    } else {
if err = certificate.CheckSignature(certificate.SignatureAlgorithm, certificate.Raw, certificate.Signature); err != nil {
                            err = rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusNotAcceptable, map[string]string{"error": fmt.Sprintf("certificate is not valid: %v", err)})
                            if err != nil {
                                log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
                            }
                        } else {
                            err = rend.JSON(writer, http.StatusOK, map[string]string{"status": "certificate is valid"})
                            if err != nil {
                                log.Errorf("could not render response: %v", err)
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I've also attempted at using the `Verify` method:

```golang
opts := cryptoX509.VerifyOptions{
    Roots:     rootChain,
    KeyUsages: []cryptoX509.ExtKeyUsage{cryptoX509.ExtKeyUsageAny},
}

_, err := certificate.Verify(verifyOpts)
```

But the message is the same one.

I would expect to both methods to pass successfully (verification given certain contraints or at least the basic signature verification).